# R Dataframe - Reassigning values to a variable (reducing one level)

Tags: r

I am trying to replace the word "Asia" - a value within a column of a dataframe whenever I am iterating over a dataframe and come across words "India" and "Japan".
Whenever I am assigning the value Asia to India (column V14) it's not assigning somehow. Trying to find out what I am doing wrong.

```
for(i in 1:nrow(training_data)){
  if (training_data[i,c("V14")] == " India")
  {
    training_data[i,c("V14")]  <- "Asia"
  }
#   else{
#     training_data[i,c("V14")]  = "Others"
#   }
}
```

Comment: Try with `ifelse` i.e `training_data$V14 <- with(training_data, ifelse(V14=="India", "Asia", "Others"))`

Comment: Make sure that you convert the column to `character` class before doing the `ifelse`

Comment: R has a variety of vectorized ways to mutate columns and manipulate data. You would not want to rely on loops since they tend to be extremely slow and not as elegant. Akrun's answer is exactly what you need. As for the mistake in your code, you need to modify to training_data$V14[i] <- 'Asia' (similar change in if condition.

Comment: You've got a space in `" India"` - is that your problem?